# Custom POJO with Left Join in jooQ

Tags: java, join, left-join, jooq

I'm doing a left join of Table A and Table B and trying to fetch the results into a custom POJO which has fields from both Table A and Table B as follows:

```
List<MyCustomPojo> res = create.select()
                         .from(TABLE_A)
                         .leftJoin(TABLE_B)
                         .on(TABLE_A.MY_CODE.eq(TABLE_B.MY_CODE))
                         .fetchInto(MyCustomPojo.class);
```

It works fine for all the fields except for the field *myCode* the one on which these two tables are joined. For me the values for *myCode* were picked up from the right table, Table B, which is NULL for all of those records in Table A that do not have a corresponding entry in Table B. I would like to know how jooQ decides which field to map to POJO and if this behavior is documented anywhere.

My goal is to fetch all the fields from Table A and Table B into the custom POJO such that *myCode* is picked up from the left table. I would appreciate your advice on the right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behaviour of [`ResultQuery.fetchInto(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchInto-java.lang.Class-) (and most other `into(Class)` methods) is specified in [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html). It can be overridden globally by [providing a custom `RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/) in your `Configuration`.

In your particular case, `DefaultRecordMapper` will map all values from your records in field order. If there's a column that appears twice, it will be mapped twice, meaning that the second value will persist in your resulting object. There are two easy workarounds:

#### Don't select the "wrong" *myCode*. This is really the most robust solution

```
List<MyCustomPojo> res = create
    .select(TABLE_A.fields())
    .select(/* all fields in TABLE_B except the ones you don't want */)
    .from(TABLE_A)
    .leftJoin(TABLE_B)
    .on(TABLE_A.MY_CODE.eq(TABLE_B.MY_CODE))
    .fetchInto(MyCustomPojo.class);
```

#### Use `RIGHT JOIN` instead:

Perhaps a bit of a hack, but this will quickly reverse the table order in your `SELECT` statement.

```
List<MyCustomPojo> res = create
    .select()
    .from(TABLE_B)
    .rightJoin(TABLE_A)
    .on(TABLE_A.MY_CODE.eq(TABLE_B.MY_CODE))
    .fetchInto(MyCustomPojo.class);
```

Finally a use-case for `RIGHT JOIN` :)

*Note, this is the only solution that will also prevent wrong values for other columns that "accidentally" share the same name.*

#### Add the "correct" *myCode* field once more.

Another hack, but it will work around the issue you're experiencing:

```
List<MyCustomPojo> res = create
    .select(TABLE_A.fields())
    .select(TABLE_B.fields())
    .select(TABLE_A.MY_CODE)
    .from(TABLE_A)
    .leftJoin(TABLE_B)
    .on(TABLE_A.MY_CODE.eq(TABLE_B.MY_CODE))
    .fetchInto(MyCustomPojo.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas! All of these options work for me and I'm going ahead with the third.